# Solving a system of 4 second order ODE's in matlab using ODE45

Tags: matlab, ode45

I need to solve this system of second order equations using ODE45 in matlab
I'm only familiar with using ODE45 with maybe one or two equations but not this many
Here is what I have but I'm not sure how to correct it:

```
function second_oder_ode

t = 0:0.001:3;   % time scale
theta = pi/2;
phi = 0;

initial_t    = 0;
initial_dtds = 0;
initial_r    = 0;
initial_drds = 0;
initial_theta    = 0;
initial_dthetads = 0;
initial_phi    = 0;
initial_dphids = 0;

[t,x] = ode45( @(t,y) rhs(t,y,theta,phi), t, [initial_t initial_dtds initial_r initial_drds initial_theta initial_dthetads initial_phi initial_dphids] );

plot(t,x(:,1));
xlabel('t'); ylabel('r');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% STATE VECTORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
t = [t, dtds];
r = [r, drds];
theta = [theta, dthetads];
phi = [phi, dphids];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function dxds=rhs(t,r, theta, phi)
    dxds_1 = t(2);
    dxds_2 = -((2/3)*R0^(2)*((3*H0/(2*cv))^(4/3))*y(1)^(1/3))*(y(4)^(2)+abs(y(3))^(2)*y(6)^(2)+abs(y(3))^(2)*(sin(y(5)))^(2)*y(8)^(2));
    dxds_3 = r(2);
    dxds_4 = -(4/(3*y(1)))*y(2)*y(4)+abs(y(3))*(y(6)^(2)+(sin(y(5)))^(2)*y(8)^(2));
    dxds_5 = theta(2);
    dxds_6 = -(2/abs(y(3)))*y(4)*y(6)-(4/(3*y(1)))*y(2)*y(6)+((sin(2*y(5)))*(y(8)^(2))/2);
    dxds_7 = phi(2);
    dxds_8 = -2*y(8)*((2/(3*y(1)))*y(2)+(cot(y(5)))*y(6)+(1/abs(y(3)))*y(4));

    dxdt=[dxdt_1; dxdt_2; dxdt_3; dxdt_4; dxdt_5; dxdt_6; dxdt_7; dxdt_8];

   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a full solution, but is longer than a comment.

You seem to be using `t` `theta` and `phi` each for two purposes.
For example, maybe change the timescale line to use `s`.

Looking at your odefun, here called `rhs`, I think it should have 2 arguments.
The first argument should be `s` (even if it is not used) and the second argument should be a vector input where the values `y(1:8)` correspond to `[t; t_s; r; r_s; theta; theta_s; phi; phi_s]`.

The expressions for `dxds_#` should only contain terms of `y` and no `t`, `r`, `theta` or `phi`.

You have typos on the line `dxdt=` which should contain `dxds` terms.

Below I've made some changes. I've not tested this; I don't have the constants `R0`, `H0` or `cv` and I think it will be uniformly zero.

Also I've removed the first occurrences of `theta` and `phi`. I'm not sure how these are supposed to feature in `rhs`.

```
function second_oder_ode

s = 0:0.001:3;   % time scale
%theta = pi/2;
%phi = 0;

initial_t    = 0;
initial_dtds = 0;
initial_r    = 0;
initial_drds = 0;
initial_theta    = 0;
initial_dthetads = 0;
initial_phi    = 0;
initial_dphids = 0;

y0 = [initial_t, initial_dtds, initial_r, initial_drds, ...
      initial_theta, initial_dthetads, initial_phi, initial_dphids];

[s,x] = ode45( @(s,y) rhs(s,y), s, y0);

plot(s,x(:,1));
xlabel('s'); ylabel('t(s)');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% STATE VECTORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%t = [t, dtds];
%r = [r, drds];
%theta = [theta, dthetads];
%phi = [phi, dphids];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function dxds=rhs(s,y)
    dxds_1 = y(2);
    dxds_2 = -((2/3)*R0^(2)*((3*H0/(2*cv))^(4/3))*y(1)^(1/3))*(y(4)^(2)+abs(y(3))^(2)*y(6)^(2)+abs(y(3))^(2)*(sin(y(5)))^(2)*y(8)^(2));
    dxds_3 = y(4);
    dxds_4 = -(4/(3*y(1)))*y(2)*y(4)+abs(y(3))*(y(6)^(2)+(sin(y(5)))^(2)*y(8)^(2));
    dxds_5 = y(6);
    dxds_6 = -(2/abs(y(3)))*y(4)*y(6)-(4/(3*y(1)))*y(2)*y(6)+((sin(2*y(5)))*(y(8)^(2))/2);
    dxds_7 = y(8);
    dxds_8 = -2*y(8)*((2/(3*y(1)))*y(2)+(cot(y(5)))*y(6)+(1/abs(y(3)))*y(4));

    dxds=[dxds_1; dxds_2; dxds_3; dxds_4; dxds_5; dxds_6; dxds_7; dxds_8];

   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it!

I've ran this, but I'm getting the errors.

Output argument "dxds" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "stackoverflow/rhs".

Error in stackoverflow>@(s,y)rhs(s,y) (line 23)
[s,x] = ode45( @(s,y) rhs(s,y), s, y0);

Comment: Hi @ful1meta1 . It wasn't supposed to be a full working example, I didn't expect it to give you your expected output, just demonstrate some places where you might need to make changes. Nevertheless, I've now corrected the last non-`end` line to define `dxds` (was `dxdt` before). I still don't expect it to give the correct answer, but it should now run (given `H0`, `R0` and `cv`).